# Unix `find` command that returns path and whether or not it's a file/directory?

Tags: file, shell, unix

When you do `ls -la` it returns each path along with info of whether or not it's a file/directory:

```
$ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x  11 viatropos  staff   374 Jan 21 21:24 .
drwxr-xr-x  41 viatropos  staff  1394 Feb  2 00:48 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 viatropos  staff    43 Jan 21 21:23 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--   1 viatropos  staff    43 Jan 21 21:23 .npmignore
-rw-r--r--   1 viatropos  staff   647 Jan 21 21:23 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 viatropos  staff  3069 Feb  5 20:17 index.js
drwxr-xr-x   8 viatropos  staff   272 Feb  5 20:06 node_modules
-rw-r--r--   1 viatropos  staff   291 Jan 21 21:24 package.json
drwxr-xr-x   4 viatropos  staff   136 Jan 21 21:23 test
```

Is there a way to do this using the `find` command (and glob `*` functionality)? So, finding all paths within `node_modules` and having it return the path and whether or not it's a file directory? Something like:

```
$ find node_modules -name 'lib/*'
d  node_modules/express/lib/
f  node_modules/express/lib/index.js
...
```

Comment: `find -ls` not doing it for you?

Comment: Is `find node_modules -exec ls -ld {} + | cut -c1,16,53-` close enough?  You might need to adjust the offsets 16 and 53 for your system, but 15 is the blank after the link count on Mac OS X, and 53 is the blank before the file name.  You get a dash instead of an `f` for files; you can fix that by piping the `cut` output through `sed 's/^-/f/'` or you can use `sed` in place of `cut` if you wish and are inventive enough.

Answer (score 2):

How about `find ... -printf '%y %p\n'`? (This is probably a GNU find extension, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this script, I called it "findfl". The "mtime" clause finds files changed in the last 3 days.

Directories will have "/" appended.

```
#!/bin/sh
# find files produced recently, matching input pattern
[ $1 ] || { echo "Usage: findfl <file-name-pattern>" ; exit ; }

TOPDIR=/home/usr/fred     #the directory you want to search
echo "Searching $TOPDIR"
find . -mtime -3 -name *$1* 2>/dev/null | xargs -n 99 ls -lptr | sed "s! ./! $TOPDIR/!g"
```